# High Ordering Function - printing out thrice

Tags: python

I want to do a high ordering function. The code is all right.
But I'm not too sure why it output 3 times with the same value.
Suppose it should be if user entering 1, it will print the first line of code, and so forth. I keep getting the same output.

```
def double(x):
    return 2*x

def square(x):
    return x*x

def cube(x):
    return x*x*x

def getInput():
    while True:
        userInput = input("Enter the number you want to test")
        try:
            if (userInput <= 0):
                print ("Please enter a valid number")
        except ValueError:
                print("Please enter a valid number")
        else:
            return userInput
            break

def getInput2():
    while True:
        userInput2 = input("Choose your options\n 1 - double \n 2 - square \n 3 - cube")
        try:
            if (userInput2 <= 0):
                print ("Please enter a valid number")
        except ValueError:
                print("Please enter a valid number")
        else:
            return userInput2
            break

userInputNum = getInput();
userInputOption = getInput2();

def doTwice(func,x):

    if func(x== 1):
        return double(double(userInputNum))
    elif func(x== 2):
        return square(square(userInputNum))
    elif func(x== 3):
        return cube(cube(userInputNum))
    else:
        print ("Please enter only 1,2 or 3")

print doTwice(double,userInputOption)
print doTwice(square,userInputOption)
print doTwice(cube,userInputOption)
```

output given (given that my input option is 1, and number I key in to calculate is 4):

```
16
16
16
```

output I want (given that my input option is 1 , and number I key in to calculate is 4):

```
16
256
262144
```

Comment: Your function `doTwice(func,x)` never uses `func` or `x`...

Comment: You never change `userInputOption` so output is always same because parameters are same.

Comment: edited my question, please take a look at the code again

Comment: What are the double(), square() and cube() functions? Are they just what the name implies?

Comment: I've updated the code, please take a look

Comment: @DanielRoseman how can I make my output different?

Comment: Your `getInput()` and `getInput2()` functions are faulty: they need to convert the input strings into numbers, using either the `int()` or `float()` functions. Are you sure that the code in your question is _identical_ to the code you're running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what happens with the call: `doTwice(double, 4)`

```
if double(4 == 1): 
   print "bla"
```

Python will evaluate the `4 == 1` expression, find a `True` value and will pass this to `double()`. `True * 2` is still `True`, thus the first line will be evaluated all the time, unless you type `1` (I think).

The code you probably want is more like this:

```
def doTwice(func,userInputNum):  
   return func(func(userInputNum)

def selectFunction(userChoice, userInputNum): 
    if userChoice == 1: 
       return doTwice(double, userInputNum)
    if userChoice == 2: 
       return doTwice(square, userInputNum)
    if userChoice == 3: 
       return doTwice(cube, userInputNum)
    else:
       print("Please enter only 1,2 or 3")

userInputNum = getInput()
userInputOption = getInput2()


print selectFunction(userInputOption)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `doTwice` always selects function based on `userInputOption`. What you probably would want is:

```
def doTwice(func, x):
    return func(func(x))
```

if you want to use `userInputOption` you could use that, but you should probably provide it as an argument:

```
def doTwice(option, x):
    if option == 1:
        func = double
    elif option == 2:
        func = square
    elif option == 3:
        func = cube
    else:
        print("Bad option:{0}".format(option))
        return
    print("{0}".format(func(x)))
```

Or you could use a `dict`:

```
def doTwice(option, x):
    try:
        func = { 
           1 : double,
           2 : square,
           3 : cube,
        }[option]
        print("{0}".format(func(x)))
    except KeyError:
        print("Invalid option: {0}".format(option))
```